# How can I change URL for blogger blog with custom domain?

Tags: blogger

I am using blogger with a custom domain name. whenever I post an image, the URL of that image is under *blogspot.com*. How can I change that to *mydomain.com*?

Comment: I might have to correct you here, images uploaded to Blogger is stored under a domain called "ggpht.com".

Comment: No, for me they are exactly under 3.bp.blogspot.com

Comment: Might have been the old type of blog. In either case, Google might be taking the initiative to avoid overloading your DNS server by splitting requests to different servers.

Comment: This blog is old, and has been deactive for years. But I'm using it with new blogger interface (inside)

Comment: The images you upload from Blogger is uploaded to your Picasa Web Albums account. You can't change it to `yourdomain/image.jpg`, if you have a web hosting account then upload it there and then link each of your image in every post.

Answer (score 2):

To just move the images off blogspot.com:

- Upload the image using Picasa-web-albums or Google+ photos first.
- Get the URL of the image file.
- then add the photo to your blog post uising the "URL" option on the file-upload dialog box.

(NB you need to choose the picture-load icon from the Compose window, not the Edit HTML window - the latter does not have the URl-upload option.)

Whether or not it's possible to move them to mydomain.com depends on how you got mydomain.com, and whether your package with the registrar include file hosting?   If so, you should just upload the pictures to that storage space using whatever tools they provide, and then use the URL as I outlined before.     However if your package doesn't include file hosting (including if you purchased mydomain.com via Blogger) then it's probably not possible (unless you transfer the domain to another domain registrar that does offer image file hosting)

And I have to wonder - why do you want images to be on mydomain.com   Is there some underlying goal you're trying to achieve here?    Share it, and someone may be able to suggest better alternatives.

Comment: Nope. Still image is not under my own domain

Comment: Ahh, sorry, I missed the bit about wanting it under  mydomain.com, rather than just not blogspot.com.

Comment: well, my goal is to prevent my blog images being filtered in my country. I have personal tech blog, but the whole blogger is filtered in my country.

Answer (score 2):

If you want your images to be under *mydomain.com*, you need to get web hosting to host those images. Google will *never* place images in the blog under *mydomain.com*.

Once you have got web hosting, upload your files to the host and use the "From a URL" function when inserting an image. This would directly *hot-link* the images from *mydomain.com*.